# Is there a way with org-capture-templates to not insert a line if initial content is blank

Tags: elisp, org-mode

I would like to have org-capture-template that does not insert certain text if a %-escape is blank. I am actually using the template with org-protocol and :immediate-finish, so I don't have the ability to manually edit and delete the blank line in a buffer. And sometimes I may select text on the web page and sometimes I may not. I am also just generally interested being able to make more dynamic templates.

Take this capture template as an example

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      (quote (("w" "capture" entry (file "~/org/refile.org")
               "* [[%:link][%:description]] :NOTE:\n%i\n%U\n" :immediate-finish t))))
```

With `org-protocol://capture://w/http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F/Stack%20Overflow/Hot%20Network%20Questions`.

I get this which is fine.

```
* [[http://stackoverflow.com/][Stack Overflow]] :NOTE:
Hot Network Questions
[2014-01-12 Sun 13:01]
```

But if I don't have text selected like this example `org-protocol://capture://w/http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F/Stack%20Overflow/`.

I get this:

```
* [[http://stackoverflow.com/][Stack Overflow]] :NOTE:

[2014-01-12 Sun 12:58]
```

I would like to know how to get rid of the blank line in this last example without having to use two templates.

My thought is to somehow use quote to build the string dynamically at template creation time, but I don't know how to get the value of %i to eval.

Comment: Please add a minimal working example: name a file instead of "", give initial contents, actual contents and expected contents.

Comment: I reworked to be example driven. I agree that makes it a better question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this auxiliary function:

```
(defun v-i-or-nothing ()
  (let ((v-i (plist-get org-store-link-plist :initial)))
    (if (equal v-i "")
        ""
      (concat v-i "\n"))))
```

And this as capture template:

```
("w" "capture" entry (file "~/refile.org")
     "* [[%:link][%:description]] :NOTE:\n%(v-i-or-nothing)%U\n"
     :immediate-finish t)
```

Comment: Awesome, the org-store-link-plist variable is the exact trick I was looking for!